# Matplotlib Interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I have a Data Frame df with two columns 'Egy' and 'fx' that I plot in this way:

```
plot_1 = df_data.plot(x="Egy", y="fx", color="red", ax=ax1, linewidth=0.85)
plot_1.set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

But then I want to smooth this curve using spline like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import numpy as np 

x_new = np.linspace(df_data['Egy'].min(), df_data['Egy'].max(),500)
f = spline(df_data['Egy'], df_data['fx'],x_new)

plot_1 = ax1.plot(x_new, f, color="black", linewidth=0.85)
plot_1.set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

And the plot I get is this (forget about the scatter blue points).
[image: Red Curve: Real Data, Black Curve: Smooth with spline]

There are a lot of "peaks" in the smooth curve, mainly at lower x. How Can I smooth this curve properly?

When I consider the "busybear" suggestion of use np.logspace instead of np.linspace I get the following picture, which is not very satisfactory either.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [mcve] i.e. a small fake dataset which we can use

Answer (score 0):

You have your x values *linearly* scaled with `np.linspace` but your plot is *log* scaled. You could try `np.geomspace` for your x values or plot without the log scale.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! I have implemented your suggestion and edit the main Question adding the new plot. You can see that the curve is not satisfactory yet

Comment: Sorry I mixed up `np.geomspace` and `np.logspace`. I've updated the answer. Hopefully that'll work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `spline` will only work well for functions that are already smooth. What you need is to [regularize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) the data and then interpolate afterwards. This will help to smooth out the bumps. Regularization is an advanced topic, and it would not be appropriate to discuss it in detail here.

Update: for regularization using machine learning, you might look into the [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library for Python.